# Unique name for loop variable in macro

Tags: c, macros

This is probably not a "best practice", but I want to add my custom loop statements:

```
#define repeat(count) for(int _repeat_i = 0; _repeat_i < (count); _repeat_i++)
```

Then this will work fine:

```
repeat(5) {
    do_stuff();
}
```

But I can't nest it:

```
repeat(5) {
    do_big_stuff();

    repeat(3) {
        do_little_stuff();
    }
}
```

... because the variable names will clash.

Any way to generate unique variable name in the macro?

Comment: Won't you usually need the loop index inside the loop? Why not modify your macro to take that in, thus manually resolving clashes?

Comment: That would be another variant of the macro, but here I don't need the index (example - I want to flash a LED 5 times). Think about the recursive macro example - there you hard-wire the loop name, but it will clash with the nested loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several compilers support the `__COUNTER__` macro variable that could be used to help avoid variable shadowing (you will still need to add a sufficiently unique prefix).

An example is given at: http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/12960046342/nearly-hygienic-c-macros-via-counter

The idea is to create a macro that take in the variable name suffix to use, then wrap that with a second macro that passes in  `__COUNTER__` to generate a unique suffix.

Answer (score 7):

A common workaround this problem is to pass the name of the variable to the macro:

```
#define repeat(v,count) for(int v = 0; v < (count); v++)
```

Now you can write things like `repeat(i,5)` and `repeat(j,3)` to avoid redefinition of variables.

You can also use `__LINE__` to compose a variable name, like this:

```
#define repeat(count) for(int _repeat_##__LINE__ = 0; _repeat_##__LINE__ < (count); _repeat_##__LINE__++)
```

It is not ideal, because two `repeat(...)` statements on the same line would produce an error.

However, for most practical purposes this macro is going to do the job:

```
repeat(2) {
    repeat(3) {
        printf("hello\n");
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/urOFKi)

Comment: Good idea, the `__COUNTER__` option mentioned by Hargobind looks better than `__LINE__` though.

Comment: @MightyPork It's harder to use `__COUNTER__` - you'd have to use two levels of macros, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to reuse the name because the counter would increment. On top of that, `__COUNTER__` is not standard, so your code would have questionable portability.

Comment: Actually, following the idea from the other answer, it's easy with counter: http://ideone.com/POevT7
Portability is OK I guess, it'll be always compiled with GCC.

Answer (score 4):

What you've written is completely fine. It will compile to:

```
for(int _repeat_i = 0; _repeat_i < (5); _repeat_i++) {
    do_big_stuff();

    for(int _repeat_i = 0; _repeat_i < (3); _repeat_i++) {
        do_little_stuff();
    }
}
```

If you really wanted unique names though, you could use the macro `__COUNTER__` or `__LINE__` to generate unique variable names.

Comment: Are you sure this will compile, and won't cause some kind of infinite loop? You can shadow a variable in nested scope? Sorry, I used to work with java.. maybe that's why I don't get this..

Comment: Yes. You can shadow variables in nested scopes in C++.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I was thinking this was a C++ question. But the above code works in both C and C++.